# How should I phrase it?

Tags: grammar, phrase-request, vocabulary

Hypothetically, I sell a variety of fresh and frozen food. The delivery fee is $50 for order below $100.

A customer has ordered $70 worth of fresh food and wants it to be delivered. I'd like to tell them it's more worth it to buy another $30 worth of goods to take advantage of the free delivery.

Their concern is they are unable to finish that much fresh food with the given time. I suggest they can buy our frozen food so that they can be kept longer if they can't consume them immediately.

Below is what I tried:

> - We have both fresh and frozen versions. You can bundle up with frozen items to make up to $100.
> - You can mix and match fresh and frozen versions to meet the min. requirement for free delivery.
> - You can add more items to make up to $100.

I think none of the above convey my thoughts concisely and coherently and I can't think of the right vocabulary to use. Is *mix and match*, *bundle* and *make up to* correctly used in this context?

Also, is it ok to use *versions* for food? For e.g. fresh and frozen versions? pre-cooked and uncooked versions?

Comment: _Fresh and frozen versions_ suggests to me 'the same type of food in both fresh and frozen form', which may not be what you mean. Why not _items_ or simply _food_? _Bundle up_ sounds inappropriate to me. I prefer version 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

> We have both fresh and frozen versions. You can bundle up with frozen items to make up to $100.

To me, "versions" is an odd choice. "We also have frozen [food/items]" would do just fine, don't over-complicate it.

Also, "bundle *up*" is what we sometimes say when you add many layers of clothing in cold weather. The sentence gave me funny mental images of someone adding frozen food into their clothing. Your suggestion of "mix and match" would work well:

> We also have frozen food, and you can mix and match to reach the $100 free delivery amount.

Comment: I think that "bundle" would be fine in this context without "up", e.g.: "You can bundle items together in order to . . ."